# Write stochastic integral equation in differential form.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

If I have a stochastic process given by

$$Y(t)=x+\int_s^t\frac{a(\tau)-\sigma(\tau)\gamma(\tau)}{Z(\tau)}d\tau + \int_s^t\frac{\gamma(\tau)}{Z(\tau)}dW(\tau)$$

where $X(s)=x$, how would I write it in differential form? If $s=0$ it would be

$$dY(t)=\frac{a(t)-\sigma(t)\gamma(t)}{Z(t)}dt + \frac{\gamma(t)}{Z(t)}dW(t).$$

But how do I do it if $t>s>0$?

Comment: The same... Notice that $dY_t=\mu_t\,\mathrm d t+\sigma _t\,\mathrm d W_t$ is a notation for $$Y_t=Y_s+\int_s^t \mu_\tau\,\mathrm d \tau+\int_s^t\sigma _\tau W_\tau.$$

Comment: @Surb Thank you!